# How to make a button stay at a bottom of a screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a button that I want to stay at the bottom of the screen, no matter how you scroll the page up or down the page. I need it to stay a fixed distance away from the bottom of the window.

How do I make it sticky like this?

Comment: `<div style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;">Basic</div>`

Comment: Try this: button { position:relative; margin-top:100%; left:50%; } Link: jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/y4PZ6/248

Answer (score 5):

To keep any element fixed on page irrelevantto scroll you need to make it position **fixed**

Please check below CSS

```
button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: But, but, what if I want to target old IE's?

Comment: I want it to stay at the bottom of the screen no matter how i scroll it up

Comment: @dev-null Only IE6 does not support position:fixed, and it's not major browser. (See browser support here.)

Comment: I positioned it fixed and is ok at the bottom of the page. What i want is for the button to stay on the button of the screen when scrolled up as it have a big margin bottom when scrolled up which i don't want.

Comment: @Mo-alanteh, can you hare code or url where I can inspect it

Answer (score 1):

just add below css:

```
button{
    position:fixed;
    left:10px;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: I want it to stay at the bottom of the screen no matter how i scroll it up

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

something like that.

Comment: I want it to stay at the bottom of the screen no matter how i scroll it up

Answer (score 1):

*To keep the button fixed at the bottom of the page even when scrolled:*

```
button { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-top:100%; 
  left:50%; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/y4PZ6/248)

*To position button at the bottom of the page but move with the scroll:*

```
button{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 5%;
        right:50%;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/BUuSr/49/)

Comment: I positioned it fixed and is ok at the bottom of the page. What i want is for the button to stay on the button of the screen when scrolled up as it have a big margin bottom when scrolled up which i don't want.

Comment: Try this: button {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:100%;
    left:20%;
    }
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/y4PZ6/248/